# SharePoint with entity framework

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I would like to use EF in SharePoint but I have got error.

1) I created model EF (Model1.edmx)

[image]

2) I added simple Linq

[image]

3) I edited web.config in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\16869 (connectionString)

4) I deploy my project

5) I get error

Probably somewhere I need to add (Model1.edmx) but I don`t know where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added .dll i assembly via gacutil